# jQuery/Js looping over Codeigniter MySQL outputted data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

```
$("#areaCodeList").click(function() {
   //onClick slideDown hidden church lists
});
```

in Javascript or jQuery how would I loop over multiple outputted database entries? What I need it to do is be able to uniquely identify the different rows and be able to act on each one rather than acting on all. I need the jQuery or Javascript to act like a Php while loop. Does this make sense to anyone?

```
<div class="areaCodeList" id="areaCodeList"><?=$row->areacode." - ".$row->locational_state;?></br></div>
```

Comment: Acting like a loop on what? Take a look at the .each() method, maybe that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 12:45PM : Change of entire page:**

http://jsfiddle.net/eEtja/ - I created this fiddle with one panel.  I rewrote the code on the page.  Now that I better understand your PHP after looking it give this a shot.  I did not modify your PHP.

I updated the JavaScript to reflect the following:  (please make sure .churchList is still a class)

```
$(document).on("click", ".areaCodeList", function(){
            $('.churchList').hide();
            $(this).next('.churchList').show();
 });
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1GQZ8ctx - I have 4 area codes outputted and no matter which one i click on the first '#churchList' is shown. It should be showing the one i clicked. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: if there are multiple div layers that use #churchList, then that is your first issue.  rename <div id="churchlist"> to div class="churchlist".  Then, change this in your $(this).on('click', function() {
                        $('.churchList').show();
                });  As far as i can see, there is only "one" churchlist element. How are you generating multiple churchList elements? as your PHP array only wraps around the content of the div, not the div itself?

Comment: i thought .each was suppose to take care of this?

Comment: right well the problem is that you are creating an array in your PHP, which is all fine and great, but when its being passed into jQuery, the data is no longer accessible as an actionable array.  you're only pushing out a PHP array.  The PHP array output has to be put into a JavaScript array so that when a numeric area code value is clicked, it triggers a display of its respective churchlist display.

Comment: Knowing that I'm still new to Javascript how would I do that?

Comment: The `on()` function should be used this way: `$(document).on("click", ".areaCodeList", function(){...});`

Comment: `$(".areaCodeList").on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('.churchList').slideDown();
  $('.churchList').slideUp();
 });`
How do i get this code to slideUp even if the next element has been clicked. What it's doing right now is sliding down then back up when clicked the first time. but i need it to slideDown on click one, then slideUp on second click. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `each()` to iterate over a group of DOM elements:

```
$(".areaCodeList").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // Your code here to act on each individual element.
});
```

More info on [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each)

Comment: Yeah the each() method came to mind. I've just never worked with it. Thanks man.